# An alternative to store dark-mode information in cookies or local-storage for faster reload

Tags: javascript, html, web, cookies, darkmode

I'm creating a static website to host my notes on the web. On that site, I have implemented a dark-mode feature based on a flag (e.g flag=0 means dark and flag=1 means light). Now, to save the previous browsing theme of the user, I'm saving the flag value in two ways...

1. Using **Cookies**
2. Using **LocalStorage**

For Cookies, I'm using the following function to extract the flag value...

```
function getCookie(cname) {
        let name = cname + "=";
        let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            let c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                document.cookie = "darkflag = 1";
            }
        }
        return "1";
    }
```

and for localStorage,

```
function getLS(cname) {
        let val = localStorage.getItem(cname);
        if (val !== null && val !== ''){
            return val;
         }
        else {
                return "1";
                localStorage.setItem("darkflag", "1");
            }
        }
```

---

Testing both these ways using local-host works perfectly, but when I've hosted them using netlify
( [**Site that uses Cookie**](https://obsidianamlan.netlify.app/) and [**Site that uses localStorage**](https://obsidian-amlan.netlify.app/) ), I'm facing a performance issue in refreshing the webpage after setting the dark mode. It reloads into the light mode, takes a little time (~1.2-1.5 sec) to read the flag data, and displays the correct theme.

**How can I remove this issue? Is there any alternative way to store the dark flag data?**

Any help/ suggestion is highly appreciable.

Thank you.

---

P.S. My dark mode function looks something like this...

```
function darkmode() {
    var darkflag = (getLS('darkflag'));
    var r = document.querySelector(':root');
    if (darkflag == 0) {
        r.style.setProperty('--bg', '#040407');
        r.style.setProperty('--font', '#eee');
        r.style.setProperty('--sidebarbg', '#111');

 and so on...
}
```

Comment: Dont think it has anything to do with your problem, but `localStorage.setItem("darkflag", "1");` in `getLS` will never run, put it before `return`
also in `getCookie` put `document.cookie = "darkflag = 1";` before `return`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm doing this. Let me see whether the problem resolves :)